# Robot class clicks within confines of applet

Tags: java, applet, mouseevent, awtrobot

For me, the robot class works but using `robot.mouseMouse(x, y);` will be the x and y of the screen. How do I make it only do the confines of the applet itself? So in other words the coordinates `1,1` would usually be the top left of the screen, but instead I want it to be the top left of the applet..

How is this achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the position. You can ask for it's `Location`

```
myApplet.getLocation();
```

And for its size

```
myApplet.getSize();
```

That way you can create a method

```
public void mouseToPosition(int x, int y){
    int zeroPosX = myApplet.getLocation().getX();
    int zeroPosY = myApplet.getLocation().getY();

    int newPosX = zeroPosX + x;
    int newPosY = zeroPosY + y;

    ...
    //now you have to check if it's in the bounds of the Applet, maybe throw an error
    //and you can add your click/move/whatever robot logic
}
```

Comment: Yes, I changed it already in the post. Just ask for the applets position. `applet.getLocation()...`

Comment: Ok, It kind of works.. Although what happens if the user moves the applet? Will the `getLocation` automatically update?